# True or False: If $x >0$, there is a number $y>0$ such that whenever $t >y$, then $t> x$.

Tags: calculus

I had this problem come up on my mid-term and my professor did not explain the answer very well. See question below:

Decide whether the following sentence is true or false:
For every number $x>0$ there is a number $y > 0$ such that whenever $t > y$ then $t > x$.

**My Reasoning**

For any $(x > 0)$, you can choose $(y = x/2)$. Now, if $(t > y)$, which means $(t > x/2)$, then certainly $(t > x)$. Therefore, the given statement holds true.

I do not feel like this answer really answers the question and seems very specific to my example. Is there a clearer and better solution?

Comment: Why not take $y=x$?  $\frac x2$ doesn't work..if $x=4$ then $t=3$ satisfies $t>\frac x2$.

Comment: "Now, if $(t > y)$, which means $(t > x/2)$, then certainly $(t > x)$" is not correct: consider $t=\frac23 x$.   Using any $y \ge x$ would work, such as $y=2x$ or $y=x+1$ or even $y=x$, since you have $t>y\ge x$.

Comment: Note that the clause ‘whenever $t>y$ then $t>x$’ is equivalent to ‘$y\geq x$’.  In symbols: $[\forall\,t,\;(t>y)\;\Rightarrow\;(t>x)]\;\iff\;(y\geq x)$.  So I suspect that something's missing here; either the equivalence of these two statements was really the point, or another statement was meant, because in isolation it's a weird thing to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know but the question does look a bit wrong imo it feels a bit trivial

Let y=x+1

So $y\gt x$

If $t\gt y \Rightarrow t\gt y\gt x$